# Nexus5 identified as Media Player (Device), instead of Storage Drive, Windows 7

Tags: storage, google

I've had the Nexus 5 for a few months, and exchange files between my PC and the phone using the USB cable frequently. I also charge the phone using the USB connected to my PC. Usually, the window pops up asking what I want to do with the device, which I ignore if I'm charging, or select Explore if I'm file-transferring. About a week or so ago, I noticed that instead of options, there were NO options on the pop-up, and just a "Do Selected every time" or whatever. But no options below. Until last night, I haven't had the need to transfer files, so I ignored it.

So last night, I closed the popup and looked in My Computer, and the normal Nexus 5 was nonexistent as a Drive. There was a Safely remove Hardware icon, so I selected it and chose Open Devices and Printers. There was my Nexus 5, under Devices, identified as Media Player under Properties. My only other options on right-click are Eject, Create Shortcut, and Troubleshoot.

I can no longer access my files. I rebooted both, checked the settings on the phone, called T-Mobile, then Google, then Iolo, my antivirus and whatever-else-it-does doer, to no avail. The kicker is, I plugged it into a buddy's computer hours earlier to retrieve a file, and it connected as storage immediately. I tried on my wife's laptop, and it does the same. So something had to have changed inadvertently on my PC, and I'm sure it's something simple, but it's beyond me.

Comment: When you connect the USB, and you swipe down the notification bar is there 2 options? Also try th eusual stuff: try a different USB port on your PC. Did you install anything recently that could conflict with the phone, USB drivers or such?

Comment: http://www.android.gs/download-and-install-google-nexus-5-usb-drivers-adb-fastboot/